# How to delete accounts from Android device in a calabash test?

Tags: android, calabash

I have an app using [Android's Authenticator](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html) mechanism and i need to test it with Calabash. I figured that to test auth properly, i should dispose of any and all accounts in the device so i can test with a clean slate.

Searching for a way to do this i've found that cleaning with `adb shell pm clear my.package` effectively cleans out all data so i integrated it into my tests with this step:

```
Given(/^i am not logged in to the app$/) do
  `#{default_device.adb_command} shell pm clear my.package`
end
```

The problem here being that this step is essentially killing the test server because android kills the app before cleaning it.

Is there any workaround for this? Anything else i can use? Or is my proposal fundamentally flawed? - I am just getting started with this BDD/Calabash thing.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, to ensure that my app always launches with intro graphics when I need it to. I set the "@reinstall" tag on the scenarios. In app_life_cycle_hooks.rb I have(which might be default content I can't really remember right now)

```
Before do |scenario|
  scenario_tags = scenario.source_tag_names
  if scenario_tags.include?('@reinstall') || !INSTALLATION_STATE[:installed]
      uninstall_apps
      install_app(ENV['TEST_APP_PATH'])
      install_app(ENV['APP_PATH'])
      INSTALLATION_STATE[:installed] = true
  end
  start_test_server_in_background
end
```

And this means that before each scenario my app is removed from the device/emulator.
Could that work for you?

Comment: I realized my approach was flawed. The skeleton cucumber-android generates already reinstalls the app between tests, effectively deleting all accounts. I forgot to update this question when the piece fell into the puzzle